# Is there a way to change the name of the files extracted using zipfile in Python?

Tags: python, zip, python-zipfile

I'm trying to extract a csv file from a zip folder and choose its name as it is saved in the new directory. This code is working well to extract the file:

```
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile(f'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\{nombre_solar_zip}', 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall('C:\\Users\\user\\\\work')
```

But the name of the file inside the zip folder is constantly changing, so I'd like to change the name so I can read it. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate members with [`ZipFile.infolist`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.infolist) and then open each member, read, and write to a file of your choice with [`ZipFile.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open).

All together, it would be like this:

```py
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile("/path/to/my-file.zip") as zip
    for member in zip.infolist():
        with zip.open(member, "r") as infile, open("new-file-name", "wb") as outfile:
            while True:
                data = infile.read(chunk_size)
                if not data:
                    break
                outfile.write(data)
```